# multiple grep wildcard sequentially

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Example:

I have a script

```sh
grep  "foo" /home/user_a/*/*_test >> list
grep -o "bar" /home/user_b/*/*_word >> list
printf "\n" >> list
```

How do I run both grep at so that * is in the same iteration?

Assuming all the files under `/home/user_a` only has a string "foo", and "bar" for files under `/home/user_b`

How to get this:

```
foobar
foobar
foobar
```

Instead of:

```
foofoofoobarbarbar
```

We can think of the wildcard like a for loop, iterating all the matched files.

Instead of waiting the first grep to finish before running the second grep, the first grep stops at the first resutlt and goes to the second grep and get the first result, and then goes back to the first grep again, and so on..

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Could you please do add samples of Input also in your question to make it more clear and let us know then.

Comment: I have added some changes, let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alternate between the output of two commands, `grep` commands in this case, then use `paste`, like this:

```
paste <(grep -h "foo" /home/user_a/*/*_test) <(grep -ho "bar" /home/user_b/*/*_word)
```

Since you didn't seem to want the filenames in the output, I added the `-h` option to both grep commands.

#### Simpler example

To see how `paste` combines the output of two different commands, try this:

```
$ paste <(echo a; echo b) <(echo 1; echo 2)
a       1
b       2
```